# Python and robotframework not INFO or WARN in log

Tags: python, robotframework

I have a project where I have to use `robotframework` to make a series of tests.
In my Python 2.7 environment I have installed `robotframework 3.0.4`.
At this point I want to use the framework in my python code (is a Django project) like this:

```
from robot import run as run_test
run_test('<path of my html test file>.html')
```

test start and create a log and report files but in the `log.html` there aren't `INFO` and `WARN` messages.
Now, if i open IDLE and make the same things:

```
>>>from robot import run as run_test
>>>run_test('<same path above>.html')
```

test run and in the `log.html` file I have my FAIL, INFO, and WARN messages logged correctly!

How is possible that from my python code for the same test `robotframework` don't log `INFO` and `WARN` and from IDLE it do?

Comment: What happens if you write the test in an individual file outside Django and run that? Or in other words, is Django's own logging messing things up?